# Is there a way to access the attribute of another object in python

Tags: python, object, instance

I'm trying to create three classes one mainly storing attribute of a person, the other two will access to the instance of a person and do a bunch of things to adjust the its attribute values.

I want to keep them in separate way so its easy to manage the content in each class and expand. I think this is not a inheritance problem so my code is obviously wrong for the goal but I have no clue what shall be done.

```
class CreatePerson():
    def __init__(self):
        self.to_do_list=[]

class Shop(CreatePerson):
    def __init__(self,CreatePerson):
        super().__init__()
    def add_element(self,a):
        self.to_do_list+=[a]


class Recreation(CreatePerson):

    def __init__(self,CreatePerson):
        super().__init__()

    def add_element(self,a):
        self.to_do_list+=[a]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    joe=CreatePerson()
    p1=Shop(joe)
    p2=Recreation(joe)
    p1.add_element('whole milk')
    p2.add_element('reading book')
    print(joe.to_do_list)
```

I was hoping it could return following, but obviously it didn't link

```
['whole milk','reading book']
```

Comment: You appear to be using Composition to give the `Shop` and `Recreation` classes access to the Todo list in the `CreatePerson` class, but this doesn't look right at all.  I'm surprised your code even executes without error.  Have a look at https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/08/20/python-3-oop-part-3-delegation-composition-and-inheritance/

Comment: Have you ever wondered what happened to the "joe" instance that you're passing to the Shop and Recreation constructor?

Comment: I do know what wrote is wrong, but just want to put the code as much as possible so I can approximate a clear question that make sense to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your `Shop` and `Recreation` objects to share their underlying `CreatePerson` object. But your code doesn't do that. As `@mike scotty` commented, you pass in `Joe`, but don't use Joe for anything. So these new objects just create their own `to_do_lists`, which are not shared. Here is something like what i imagine you want:

```
class CreatePerson():
    def __init__(self):
        self.to_do_list = []
    def add_element(self, a):
        self.to_do_list += [a]


class Shop():
    def __init__(self, CreatePerson):
        self.my_person = CreatePerson
    def add_element(self, a):
        self.my_person.add_element(a)


class Recreation():
    def __init__(self, CreatePerson):
        self.my_person = CreatePerson
    def add_element(self, a):
        self.my_person.add_element(a)

>>> joe=CreatePerson()
>>> p1=Shop(joe)
>>> p2=Recreation(joe)
>>> p1.add_element('whole milk')
>>> p2.add_element('reading book')
>>> print(joe.to_do_list)
['whole milk', 'reading book']
```

So now Shop and Recreation aren't instances of a `CreatePerson`, but they do take a `CreatePerson` in their constructor, and store a reference to that person. And when you call `add_element` on those objects, they call the new `add_element` method that their `CreatePerson` has.

I'd just like to note that I don't think this is exactly the right abstraction - your Shop has one-and-only-one person, as does your Recreation. But I took it at face value for the purposes of answering this question.

Hope that helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: thanks for the answer. The difference is I don’t want the add_element() method in the CreatePerson class, actually its a bunch if methods that I want to later defined and will be quite different depending if the person is doing Shop or Recreation.

Comment: I think I figured it out by making minor changes to your example. Thanks